# Interfaces and classes in JAVA

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

Lets have following Class Diagram as an example

[image]

I made similar classes in java like below

```
public class B {

}

public interface C {

}

public class A extends B implements C {

}

public class D {
    C c = new A();
    C c1 = new B(); // Error, Type mismatch: cannot convert from B to C. WHY ?
    C c2 = (C) new B(); // Works fine. This makes me confuse ... What does this actually mean ?
}
```

Can anybody explain this ?

Comment: Why my question is downvoted ?

Comment: @Junaid ignore those downvotes without comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
C c1 = new B()
```

You can never instantiate class B as interface C since it doesn't implement interface C.

```
C c2 = (C) new B()
```

In the second case you are explicitly casting the instance of B to type C. The compiler allows this, but you'll get a run-time exception.

Answer (score 1):

Why `C c2 = (C) new B();` does not compile: see Ankur Shanbhag's answer.

`C c2 = (C) new B();` may compile well, but since `c2` is a `B` object and thus cannot be converted to `C`, this will throw an exception at runtime.

I made an example:

```
public class D {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c2 = (C) new B();           
        System.out.println(c2);
    }
}
```

And received an exception:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: casting.B cannot be cast to C`

Answer (score 0):

```
C c1 = new B(); // Error, Type mismatch: cannot convert from B to C. WHY ?
```

You can refer to derived classed only through super class references. In your case, `C` is a not a super class of `B`. Hence the error

```
C c2 = (C) new B(); // This makes me confuse ... What does this actually mean ?
```

Compiler wont allow you to perform the above casting. To cast from one type to another, both the classes must be in the same Object hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Extends means "is a kind of".

`A` is a kind of `B`, so it has all the features of `B`.

However, `B` *isn't* a kind of `A`, so it doesn't necessarily have all the features of `A`, including implementing the `interface C`. That's why you get the type mismatch.

But in this case:

```
C c2 = (C) new B()
```

*Casting* tells the compiler "Don't check this because I know what I'm doing." So it may compile.

But if at runtime the object you *actually* cast can't be typed as a `C`, you'll get a `ClassCastException`. In your case, you are casting a `B` to a `C`, and a `B` isn't a kind of `C` any more than it is a kind of `A`. So you'll get the exception.